# Issue in deploying a simple docker image to openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin, rhel7

I was prototyping Openshift Origin latest version.

OS : RHEL 7.3

Docker : 17.05.0-ce

oc v1.5.1+7b451fc

kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4

- Installation is done using a sudo user
- Started the openshift using `oc cluster up`
- Logged into openshift as the default user developer
- Tried to deploy the docker helloworld app using `oc new-app hello-world`
- Used `oc get pod` to get the status
- Status is error

> NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
>
> hello-world-1-deploy       0/1       Error     0          57m

- Checked the logs using `oc logs hello-world-1-deploy` the error shown is

> error: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no
>   such file or directory

Tried google and got a lot of similar issue references, most said it is fixed in the latest versions (or similar answers). Looks like a kubernetes issue, but still no luck. Being a newbie is not getting the direction. Can anyone give some idea about this error.

Errors found on running `oc adm diagnostics`

```
[Note] Running diagnostic: DiagnosticPod
   Description: Create a pod to run diagnostics from the application standpoint

ERROR: [DCli2012 from diagnostic DiagnosticPod@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/client/run_diagnostics_pod.go:155]
   See the errors below in the output from the diagnostic pod:
   [Note] Running diagnostic: PodCheckAuth
          Description: Check that service account credentials authenticate as expected

   ERROR: [DP1001 from diagnostic PodCheckAuth@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/pod/auth.go:53]
          could not read the service account token: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory

   [Note] Running diagnostic: PodCheckDns
          Description: Check that DNS within a pod works as expected

   [Note] Summary of diagnostics execution (version v1.5.1+7b451fc):
   [Note] Errors seen: 1

[Note] Running diagnostic: NetworkCheck
   Description: Create a pod on all schedulable nodes and run network diagnostics from the application standpoint

ERROR: [DNet2001 from diagnostic NetworkCheck@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/network/run_pod.go:77]
   Checking network plugin failed. Error: User "developer" cannot get clusternetworks at the cluster scope


[Note] Running diagnostic: ClusterRegistry
   Description: Check that there is a working Docker registry

ERROR: [DClu1006 from diagnostic ClusterRegistry@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/cluster/registry.go:209]
   The "docker-registry" service exists but has no associated pods, so it
   is not available. Builds and deployments that use the registry will fail.

[Note] Running diagnostic: ClusterRouterName
   Description: Check there is a working router

ERROR: [DClu2007 from diagnostic ClusterRouter@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/cluster/router.go:156]
   The "router" DeploymentConfig exists but has no running pods, so it
   is not available. Apps will not be externally accessible via the router.
```

### Resolution (update)

1. Uninstalled the 1.13 latest and installed the 1.12 latest docker-engine.
2. Installation done using the centos repository. [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/v1.12/engine/installation/linux/rhel/)
3. Commands used

> Installing dependency se-linux
>
> sudo yum install docker-engine-selinux-1.12.6-1.el7.centos.noarch
>
> Installing docker-engine
>
> sudo yum install docker-engine-1.12.6-1.el7.centos.x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downgrading docker to 1.13.1 per [this comment](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13865#issuecomment-301019326).

Comment: Thank you it worked . Also the latest version (1.13) of docker is not officially supported on RHEL, so I installed the latest 1.12 version. Adding the install commands (a section in the question) for future reference